# How to join tables without key in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to join Table A and Table B, but there is no related key. And, Table C is my expected result table.

[image]

I have tried to use ROW_NUMBER(), but it did not serve my expectation. Below is my current code.

```
SELECT TableA.CustoemerId as CustoemerId, TableB.RewardCode as RewardCode,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TableA.CustoemerId) as TableA_RowNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TableB.RewardCode) as TableB_RowNumber

FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA_RowNumber = TableB_RowNumber
```

Comment: Why do you want to pair unrelated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. First apply the row_number(), then join:

```
select tA.CustoemerId, tB.RewardCode
from 
(SELECT CustoemerId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustoemerId) as TableA_RowNumber 
from TableA) tA
inner join
(select RewardCode,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RewardCode) as TableB_RowNumber
FROM TableB) tB
 ON TableA_RowNumber = TableB_RowNumber;
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between the values from tableA and tableB In other words, do they need to match by the digits at the end of the values (01 to 01) or is it just as they appear when they are sorted alphabetically (if the first table didn't have is:C0001, would the first row the result be C0002, HAPPY01 or will it be C002, HAPPY02 -and HAPPY01 wouldn't be in the results?

Comment: @userMT,  are you asking me or to OP? As I understand those C0001, HAPPY01 ... are all fictionary and could be anything. All he wanted to was to match  and "zip" first N rows from tableA to first N rows from tableB, both ordered on their CustoemerId and RewardCode. I don't know why he would want to do that.

Comment: I was asking @Ben Inm, sorry. If the question is as you described, your answer seems the right one.